# Why am I unable to use Qt with Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2008

I have downloaded Qt for [Visual Studio 2008 for Windows](http://releases.qt-project.org/qt4/source/qt-win-opensource-4.8.1-vs2008.exe) 4.8.1.

I have run `configure.exe` from the command prompt.

But I can not find nmake.exe or make.exe anywhere in my "C:\QT\4.8.1" - directory.

Therefore, I am unable to use Qt with Visual Studio 2008.

What to do now?

Comment: Do you really need to compile Qt by yourself? How about using this: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Finally, I found my solution.

Step (1).  Download and Install [QT for Visual Studio 2008 4.8.1](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/windows-cpp-vs2008).

Step (2). Download and Install [QT Visual Studio Addin 1.1.10](http://qt.nokia.com/downloads/visual-studio-add-in).

Nothing else is needed at all.

Now I am able to Create, Compile and Run my "Hello World"- QT application straightaway.

Answer (score 4):

`nmake` is the make that comes with Visual Studio.

You should have run whatever instructions you're following from a Visual Studio command line prompt, which contains all the right PATH settings for using `nmake` and `cl` on the command line.

Comment: I also recommend that you build from a "Visual Studio Command Prompt". There should be links in your start menu for x86 and possibly x64 command prompts. Besides setting up your path to nmake these command paths will properly set a few environment variables for the compiler and linker.

Answer (score 0):

You could use QT Creator as your IDE instead.  I found getting it up and running is fairly issue-free.